# Get values from several UITextFields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a grouped static UITableViewController, with 3 rows per section. Each row contains a UITextField. How do I get the value for each UITextField?

So far, what I've seen is how to get the value of one UITextField. What should I do if I have to get more than one.

I plan to put the values of these fields in a NSMutableDictionary.

Here's my code for making the table view: (irrelevant parts are omitted)

```
#import "AddItemTableViewController.h"
#import "iMonggoFetcher.h"

@interface AddItemTableViewController() <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *productItem;

//required
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *stockNoTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *retailPriceTextField;

//basic info
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *costTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descriptionTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *barcodesTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tagsTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *exemptFromTaxSwitch;

//advanced features
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *allowDecimalQuantitiesSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *enableOpenPriceSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *disableDiscountSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *disableInventorySwitch;

@end

@implementation AddItemTableViewController
@synthesize productItem = _productItem;


@synthesize stockNoTextField = _stockNoTextField;
@synthesize nameTextField = _nameTextField;
@synthesize retailPriceTextField = _retailPriceTextField;
@synthesize costTextField = _costTextField;
@synthesize descriptionTextField = _descriptionTextField;
@synthesize barcodesTextField = _barcodesTextField;
@synthesize tagsTextField = _tagsTextField;
@synthesize exemptFromTaxSwitch = _exemptFromTaxSwitch;
@synthesize allowDecimalQuantitiesSwitch = _allowDecimalQuantitiesSwitch;
@synthesize enableOpenPriceSwitch = _enableOpenPriceSwitch;
@synthesize disableDiscountSwitch = _disableDiscountSwitch;
@synthesize disableInventorySwitch = _disableInventorySwitch;


- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.productItem setValue:self.stockNoTextField.text forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCT_STOCK_NO];
    [self.productItem setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCT_NAME];
    [self.productItem setValue:self.retailPriceTextField.text forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCT_RETAIL_PRICE];

}

#pragma mark - UITextField 

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // optionally trigger delegate method here
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //[self.stockNoTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.stockNoTextField.delegate = self;
    self.nameTextField.delegate = self;
    self.retailPriceTextField.delegate = self;
    //will do the rest later, just trying it out for now
}




@end
```

Comment: show us your code for making UITableViewCell..

Comment: please see edits above @AdilSoomro.

Comment: show us your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: I don't have a code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can make properties of these fields.. and then get the text by the property name.text

2) You can try giving the fields a tag and then get these fields using viewwithtag method. and then their text.

Comment: when you create a text field .. then add a line Yourtextfiel.tag = some integer ..  later in code when you need values. you can do UitextField *a = (UitextField *) (self.view getviewwithtag :some integer)  . there are spelling mistake in the current code.. don't remember the exact syntax.. so use autocomplete)

Comment: if you need to save all the values of the text field..make all text fields tag in ascending order like 1 to 6 ..or 8..etc..then make a for loop . for i = 0 and i <max tag..i++ then get the text field for the current i and then add that value to dictionary

Answer (score 0):

you can take values of each textFields in a array by textField.text.

Comment: is that a property of UITextField?